# how to get the keys of a nscoder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, key-value-observing

Is there a way to get the keys used in a NSCoder that has encoded a storyboard file? I see PSTCollectionView has used a lot of undocumented keys, how did they get them?

Specifically, I want the key used when you set a UITableViewController to use a UIRefreshControl automatically in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XIB (XML Interface Builder) is a file created in XML.

You can open it using textEdit or wordPad. So, problem is half solved!!!

Read the xml of xib/nib file and parse it. Read all the Keys from there.

Snipped of MainMenu.xib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <archive 
  type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Cocoa.XIB" version="8.00"> 
   <data> <int key="IBDocument.SystemTarget">1080</int>     
       <string key="IBDocument.SystemVersion">11D50</string>
       <string key="IBDocument.InterfaceBuilderVersion">2457</string>         
       <string key="IBDocument.AppKitVersion">1138.32</string>
       <string key="IBDocument.HIToolboxVersion">568.00</string>
       <object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="IBDocument.PluginVersions"> 
          <string key="NS.key.0">com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CocoaPlugin</string> 
          <string key="NS.object.0">2457</string>       
       </object>
```

Comment: That isn't what I need. Xcode seems to compile the files and in that step it changes the keys. A .storyboard file is .storyboardc in the app bundle for example

Comment: Yes, but it seems the .storyboardc file is just a directory of the compiled .nib files which contains something that looks like keys. Hrmm, how to decode this file...

Comment: Eventually this lead to the answer. The keys are partially visible in the compiled .nib files if opened in TextEdit. The rest is a bit of guesswork it seems